# ngx bootstrap alert - detect on close event

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

How can I detect if an alert has been closed using Angular? I am using ngx bootstrap: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/alerts

Is there a way to detect if onClosed is called?

HTML:

```
<alert type="success" [dismissible]="dismissible">Detect if I am closed or open</alert>
```

my-component.component.ts:

```
alertIsClosed = false;

someFunction(detectAlertIsClosed) {
   alertIsClosed = true;
}
```

Comment: please refer output section in this link https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/alerts#alert-component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Alert` component provides an event called `onClosed`. You need to use it.

From the [**Documentation**](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/alerts#alert-component)

> onClosed - This event fires when alert closed, $event is an instance of
>   Alert component

Register to it and add the handler

**Markup**

```
<alert type="success" [dismissible]="dismissible" (onClosed)="onClosed($event)">
   Detect if I am closed or open
</alert>
```

**Component**

```
public onClosed($event) {

}
```

Comment: This works. Is there also a method to detect isOpen?

Comment: @simple No, there is not

Comment: Only `onClosed` and `onClose`